# Mysql for small web app

Tags: mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

Im about to start a small web application for a customer that the main purpose is to upload documents for specific customer and other information.

I dont want to use SQL Server because licensing cost, so I would like to know if MySQL is a realible and good replacement for this scenario.

Appreciate any advise. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you host with a major provider, you WILL NOT have any problems with SQL Server licensing,  a small number of databases is ALWAYS included in with the major web hosting companies.

SQL Server is so robust, you can use the server tools with sql express.  You can also pay for the Developer Version of SQL Server Management for $50.  Yes, only $50 bucks.  There is CE compact edition etc...

I went the whole Mysql and PostgresSQL route years ago, and I look back regretting it.  Sure you CAN wire up MVC or regular Web Forms ASP.NET with these other databases, but I'm confident that you will regret it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs and where your application will be launched in the end - if it's a hosting, then you have to rely on database engines they offer.
However, I would recommend PostgreSQL http://postgresql.org/
It is also a free database engine, but more powerful and offer better performance if properly tuned.
Some of the nice features are:

- PLPGSQL included
- possibility to extend easily with PlPython or C function
- index on immutable function
- partial indexes
- a couple of index types i.e. specialized for full text search

Just read about PostgreSQL and try it.